# Быстрый способ узнать есть ли значение переменной в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть ли "быстрый" способ узнать есть ли значение переменной в массиве?

```
string My="Example";
string[] Эталон = new string[10] {"Example", "Еще", "Какие-то", "Строки"...}

if (is_in_massive(My,Эталон))
  i_am_happy();
```

Задаю вопрос для оптимизации кода. Есть ли такое is_in_massive? Я новичок.

Comment: `if(Эталон.Contains(My)){....}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужна быстрая проверка вхождения строки в набор? Тогда замените тип вашего эталона:

```
string[] эталон = new string[10] {"Example", "Еще", "Какие-то", "Строки"...}
//меняем на
HashSet<string> эталон = new HashSet<string>(){"Example", "Еще", "Какие-то", "Строки"...};
```

Теперь `эталон.Contains("проверяемая строка")` будет работать практически мгновенно и с постоянной скоростью, независимо от того есть ли искомое значение в наборе или нет (да исключения есть, но только для очень больших наборов при наличии коллизий в хэш-таблице).

В обычном массиве тоже можно вызвать данный метод, есть соответствующий метод расширения в `System.Linq`, но будет использован такой же линейный перебор элементов, как в случае с прямым поиском с помощью явного цикла, только спрятанный в метод расширения. Т.е. значения из начала списка, при проверке, будут обнаруживаться быстрее чем значения из конца списка или значения, отсутствующие в списке.

HashSet в данном случае будет использовать собственный метод, который использует все преимущества хэш-таблиц для поиска. И хотя для поиска в коротком наборе значений, эффект от такой замены может быть и не заметен, то на длинном наборе да еще и при поиске несуществующего в наборе элемента (т.е гарантированный перебор всего списка в случае массива) вы его заметите однозначно. Короткий набор это единицы, возможно, пара десятков позиций в списке, не измерял, можете померить самостоятельно, если интересно.

---

Документация [`HashSet<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте код наподобие:

```
if(Эталон.Contains(My)){.. ..}
```